# Auf/im Wikipedia

Tags: preposition

> Das habe ich auf/im Wikipedia gelesen.

Welche Präposition benutzt man hier? Man sagt "im Internet", also vielleicht "im Wikipedia"?

Comment: Da Wikipedia weiblich ist, kann _im_ schon mal nicht stimmen. Wenn, dann _in der Wikipedia_.

Comment: Man würde wahrscheinlich keine von beiden, sodern "bei" nehmen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### in/im

**Das Internet** ist sächlich, daher kann man etwas *»im«* (=*»in dem«*) Internet finden und lesen.

**Die Wikipedia** ist aber weiblich. Daher kann man im Dativ nicht den Artikel *»dem«* verwenden, und daher auch nicht <del>*»im = in dem Wikipedia«*</del> sagen. Richtiger wäre *»in der Wikipedia«*.

Aber *Wikipedia* ist ein Eigenname, und Eigennamen werden meist ohne Artikel verwendet. Umgangssprachlich ist, abhängig von der Region, der Artikel zwar mancherorts durchaus üblich, aber standardsprachlich verwendet man Namen meist ohne Artikel. (Aber auch hier gibt es Ausnahmen.)

Daher:

> falsch:
>   <del>Das habe ich **im** Wikipedia gefunden.</del>
>
> richtig:
>   Das habe ich **in** Wikipedia gefunden.
>
> auch richtig, aber weniger häufig verwendet:
>   Das habe ich **in der** Wikipedia gefunden.

---

### auf

Ich habe oben absichtlich das Verb ausgetauscht (*»gefunden«* statt *»gelesen«*), weil man im Zusammenhang mit *finden* eher die Präposition *in* verwendet. Das hat damit zu tun, dass man beim vorausgehenden Suchen oftmals einen Behälter (z.B. eine Truhe, Schachtel) durchwühlt, und dann den gewünschten Gegenstand eben im Inneren dieses Behälters (also *»in«* dem Behälter) findet. (Natürlich kann man auch etwas *auf* einer Fläche suchen, allerdings glaube ich, dass mehr Menschen mit Suchen das Durchwühlen eines Behälters assoziieren als das Scannen einer Fläche.)

Wenn man etwas liest, steht die Schrift, die man liest, eigentlich immer **auf** einer Oberfläche (nicht *in* einem Behälter), daher passt zum Verb *»lesen«* die Präposition *»auf«* besser als *»in«*. (Aber: Man liest etwas *in* einer Zeitung, *in* einem Buch)

Bei virtuellen Flächen/Behältern verschwimmt aber der Unterschied zwischen *»auf der Oberfläche«* und *»im Inneren«*, weil es eine Sache der Interpretation ist, ob man z.B. Wikipedia als eine große Fläche betrachtet, *auf* der viele Beiträge stehen, oder ob man sie als einen großen Behälter ansieht, *in* dem viele Beiträge lagern. Beide Sichtweisen sind möglich, daher sind auch beide Präpositionen möglich.

> ok: Das habe ich auf Wikipedia gelesen.
>   ok: Das habe ich in Wikipedia gelesen.

Wegen des Verbs *lesen* würde ich persönlich aber dennoch für *auf* plädieren.

---

### Fazit

Ob man *»auf«* oder *»in«* verwendet, hängt hauptsächlich davon ab, ob man Wikipedia als Fläche oder als Behälter interpretiert. Beides ist möglich. Zusätzlich hat auch die Wahl des Verbs einen Einfluss darauf, welche Sichtweise (und damit welche Präposition) als passender empfunden wird.

Comment: Wenn ich den (Eigen-) Namen *Wikipedia* in deiner Antwort durch einen anderen Eigennamen eines Lexikons ersetze, erhalte ich: »Das habe ich *in Brockhaus* gefunden/gelesen.« Das erscheint mir so falsch, dass ich mich frage, wieso standardsprachlich »in Wikipedia« richtig sein soll.

Comment: @Jan: **Der Brockhaus** ist ja auch nicht weiblich, sondern männlich, wie auch *der Duden, der Wahrig* usw. Das sind alles Lexika, die nach den Nachnamen ihrer ersten Herausgeber benannt sind. Für solche Eigennamen hat sich eingebürgert, sie immer *mit* Artikel zu verwenden. Die Wikipedia passt nicht in dieses Schema.

Comment: So klingt es meiner Meinung nach am „standardsprachlichsten“: „**in der Wikipedia**“ und „**auf Wikipedia**“

Comment: Für mich klingt am natürlichsten (in der mündlichen) Sprache: *Das habe ich **bei** Wikipedia gefunden.* Oder aber man vermeidet die Präposition, eben weil sie strittig ist, ganz und sagt etwas wie: *Das habe ich **von** Wikipedia.*

Comment: Wikipedia selbst bezeichnet sich im Text als "die Wikipedia". Ich würde eher zu "in der Wikipedia" oder "auf Wikipedia" tendieren https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutschsprachige_Wiki1pedia

Comment: @LurioTabasco Die Verwendung in deinem Link ist interessant, weil nicht konsistent. ;) Überwiegend verwenden sie die Variante mit Artikel, was auch meinem Sprachgefühl entspricht: »in der deutschsprachigen Wikipedia«, »die Artikel der Wikipedia«, »die gesamte Wikipedia«, etc. Aber nicht immer: »Vergleich zwischen Wikipedia und der Online-Ausgabe des Brockhaus«, »Die meisten Nutzer von Wikipedia«.

Comment: Es scheint so, als ob die Semantik eine Rolle spielt; Ist von Wikipedia explizit als Enzyklopädie die Rede, so wird "die Wikipedia" benutzt. Wenn Wikipedia aber als Wikipedia die Website benutzt wird, so wird Wikipedia Artikellos, wie z.B. auch "ebay" oder "youtube". Das würde sich auch mit meinem Gefühl decken.  @HubertSchölnast nur "in Wikipedia", empfinde ich persönlich als falsch, es müsste "in der Wikipedia" heißen, weil dabei von der Enzyklopädie die Rede ist.

Comment: Zur Frage »in« vs. »in der«: Ich habe bereits bei vielen anderen Fragestellungen festgestellt, dass es zwischen Österreich und Deutschland oftmals erhebliche Unterschiede bei der Verwendung von Artikeln gibt (auf welcher Seite dabei Bayern steht, ist vermutlich von Fall zu Fall verschieden, jedenfalls ist es mir nicht immer klar). Ich glaube, dass wir es hier mit einem weiteren Beispiel für diese Art der Unterschiedlichkeit zu tun haben. Ich persönlich käme niemals auf die Idee »in der Wikipedia« zu sagen. Warum sagt eigentlich niemand »Das habe ich **auf der** Wikipedia gelesen«?

Comment: Siehe: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/40879/1487