# Ist irgendwo »auf der Wikipedia« üblich?

Tags: word-usage, article

In einer [Antwort auf eine andere Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/40862/1487) habe ich behauptet, dass folgende Präpositionen im Zusammenhang mit dem Nomen *Wikipedia* eine gute Wahl wären, wobei ich empfohlen habe, die Präposition vom Verb abhängig zu machen:

> 1. Das habe ich **in** Wikipedia gefunden.
> 2. Das habe ich **auf** Wikipedia gelesen.

In den zahlreichen Kommentaren wurde dabei kritisiert, dass folgende Version besser als Variante 1 sei, weil sie zusätzlich auch einen Artikel enthält:

> 3. Das habe ich **in der** Wikipedia gefunden.

Aber niemand hat sich zu Wort gemeldet, um für diese Version als Ersatz von Variante 2 zu plädieren:

> 2. Das habe ich **auf der** Wikipedia gelesen.

Ich lese etwas **auf der** Tafel oder **auf dem** Schild, warum also nicht **auf der** Wikipedia?

Mir persönlich kommt *»auf der Wikipedia«* ähnlich gekünstelt und hölzern vor wie *»in der Wikipedia«*. Aber das kann durchaus auch daran liegen, dass wir in Österreich ohnehin Artikel in vielen Situationen anders verwenden als Deutsche nördlich des Weißwurst-Äquators. (Auf welcher Seite die Bayern von Fall zu Fall stehen, ist mir leider nicht immer ganz klar.) (D: *der Yoghurt; das Spray. Susi trinkt eine Cola.* Ö: *das Yoghurt; der Spray. Die Susi trinkt ein Cola.*)

Ist auch *»auf der Wikipedia«* ein Fall, in dem sich D und Ö unterscheiden?

Falls *»auf der Wikipedia«* auch in deutschen Ohren exotisch klingt: Warum ziehen Deutsche dann im Fall von *»in (der) Wikipedia«* die Version mit Artikel vor?

Comment: Wahrscheinlich weil es auch heißt "in der Zeitung lesen", "im Internet". Ich sage übrigens einfach "im Wiki" (das ja sächlich ist). ;-)

Comment: "in der" habe ich übrigens in NRW noch nie wen sagen gehört, genauso wie "auf der". Die Verwendung von "auf" erfolgt wohl, wenn man Wikipedia als Webseite versteht. Analog zu "das habe ich auf spiegel.de/bild.de/etc. gelesen". Da fehlt auch immer der Artikel.

Comment: Mir (Norddeutscher) kommt "auf der Wikipedia" und "in der Wikipedia" auch seltsam/gekünstelt vor. Ich hab überlegt, ob es andere Beispiele gibt, wo man im normalen Sprachgebrauch den Artikel weg lässt, aber mir fällt keins ein, außer eben Namen von Internetseiten. Genau so würde ich z. B. auch ohne Artikel sagen: "Das habe ich auf stackexchange.com gelesen".

Comment: Mir erscheinen Formulierungen wie „in der Wikipedia“ vor allem Wikipedia-intern eher üblich, z. B. [hier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Urheberrechte_beachten). Da wird fast ausschließlich die Variante mit Artikel benutzt. Aber nach „auf der Wikipedia“ sucht man auch dort vergeblich. Warum ich auch lieber „in der Wikipedia“ und „auf Wikipedia“ sage, weiß ich selbst nicht so genau.

Comment: In meiner Umgebung sagt man meistens "bei Wikipedia". "Auf der Wikipedia" sagt niemand. Man würde sagen "im Brockhaus" oder "in der Encyclopedia Britannica". Jedoch ist Wikipedia für mein Empfinden durchaus nicht anerkannt als eigenständige Autorität mit einer einheitlichen "Persönlichkeit". Vielmehr ist jedem, den ich kenne, der sich mal auf Wikipedia-Beiträge bezieht, bewusst, dass Wikipedia eine Sammlung von Beiträgen unterschiedlichster Autoren von mal hoher, mal nicht so hoher Qualifikation ist. Dieses Bewusstsein hindert uns daran, von "**der** Wikipedia" zu sprechen.

Comment: @Zac67 [Don't abbreviate "Wikipedia" as "Wiki"!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Don%27t_abbreviate_%22Wikipedia%22_as_%22Wiki%22!)

Comment: @Loong I use several wikis, and usually the context is clear.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann richtig. Wie in "♪♪... schlaag nach bei Otto, ...♪♪"

Comment: @anion Das ist interessant, denn mir als Bayer kommt »in Wikipedia« (ohne Artikel) extrem gekünstelt vor und es fällt mir schwer vorzustellen, dass Leute tatsächlich so sprechen würden (wenn man hyperkorrigierende Deutschlehrer außen vor lässt).

Answer (score 4):

Die meisten Wortbildungen im Deutschen, die mit modernen Medien zu tun haben, versuchen sich an (mehr oder weniger guten, sich teilweise auch widersprechenden) Analogien wie

- Eine E-Mail ist eine Art Brief, deshalb kann man sie *schicken*
- Eine *web site* ist eine Seite eines Magazins, deswegen heißt sie **Seite** (argh!)
- Eine *web site* ist eine Örtlichkeit im Netz, deswegen kann man sie *besuchen*

Zur Wikipedia kann man natürlich ebenfalls beliebig viele, sich teilweise auch widersprechende Analogien finden wie:

- Wikipedia ist ein Nachschlagewerk, deswegen kann man *bei ihr* nachsehen, wie *bei Otto nachschlagen*
- Wikipedia ist eine Art Buch, deswegen kann man *in ihr* nachlesen (wie "im Duden nachlesen")
- Wikipedia ist eine *web site* (siehe oben "*Seite*"), deswegen kann man *auf ihr nachschauen*

Wenn man also *web site* ohne schlechtes Gewissen mit "Webseite" übersetzt (ich krieg's nicht richtig hin), dann kann man *auf einer Seite* natürlich auch nachsehen.

Deutlich gebräuchlicher dürften aber **bei** und **in** als passende Präpositionen sein. Ich höre *auf* sehr selten, dann meistens von sehr IT- und Englisch-unaffinen Menschen.

Wegen deiner Zweitfrage nach dem Artikel: Man sagt ja auch "im Duden" oder "im Bronstein nachschlagen" mit einem verschmolzenen Artikel und "sich in die Ilias vertiefen", warum soll man dann nicht "in der Wikipedia schauen" sagen? Wenn ich "bei" verwende, lasse ich den Artikel aber weg.

Comment: "bei Otto nachlesen" - Wer ist dieser Otto? Ich kenne den Otto-Versand und Otto Waalkes, aber bei keinem von beiden würde ich etwas *nachlesen*.

Comment: Der Duden, der Knigge, der Wahrig, der Brockhaus, der Jander/Blasius, der Hollemann-Wiberg, der Beilstein usw. sind lauter Bücher, die nach ihren Erst-Herausgebern bzw. Autoren benannt sind. Das ist eine eigene Kategorie von Eigennamen. Diese Namen von Büchern werden immer mit Artikel verwendet. Wikipedia gehört aber nicht in diese Kategorie, daher hilft ein Vergleich mit solchen Büchern nicht wirklich weiter.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Das kennst du möglicherweise nicht - War ein uralter Werbesong des Otto-Versands, in seinem Katalog nachzuschlagen - "Schlag' nach bei Otto, denn da steht was drin".

Comment: Inwiefern beantwortet dein Beitrag meine Frage "Ist irgendwo »auf der Wikipedia« üblich?" Er beantwortet aber eine [andere Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/40861/1487). Vielleicht solltest du diesen Beitrag dort posten und hier löschen?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Hast du die letzten 3 Absätze gelesen?

Comment: Ja, habe ich. Du referierst darin über verschiedene Präpositionen (*auf* vs. *bei* vs. *in*) Danach habe ich nicht gefragt, aber genau danach wurde [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/40861/1487) gefragt. Ich habe nach gefragt: *"Ist irgendwo »auf der Wikipedia« üblich?"*

Comment: @HubertSchölnast *Ich höre **auf** sehr selten, dann meistens von sehr IT- und Englisch-unaffinen Menschen.* Mehr kann ich nicht dazu sagen.

Comment: Ich habe die Antwort als richtig markiert, allerdings gefällt mir dir eingebaute Bewertung nicht, "Etwas auf einer Seite lesen" ist für mich die richtige Analogie und ich kenne es so seit den Anfängen des WWW. Ich würde solche Zusätze wie "argh" weglassen und ggf. extra die Ablehnung erläutern, wenn es sein muss. Es ist halt Sprachgebrauch und hat sich so entwickelt.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia ist ein Eigenname und im Norden verwenden wir eher keine Artikel vor Eigennamen. Deshalb klingt

> auf der Wikipedia

nördlich des Weißwurstäquators, z.B. für mich falsch. Wie **tofro** richtig bemerkt, gibt es allerdings auch für uns Marken und Eigennamen, die mit Artikel verwendet werden. Siehe dazu z.B. http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/fragen.ansicht?v_id=34

Siehe allg. zu Namen z.B. https://deutschegrammatik20.de/das-substantiv-nomen/artikel-gebrauch/

Nachtrag: Ich denke zum Verständnis insgesamt ist es wichtig, hier zwei Fragen klar zu trennen:

1) *Mit oder ohne bestimmten Artikel:* siehe meine Antwort oben

2) *Wahl der Präposition:* gut in der Antwort von **tofro** beschrieben. Diese richtet sich nicht immer nur nach dem Verb, sondern in vielen Fällen nach dem Objekt. Z.b. wäre m.E., in Kombination mit *lesen* oder *finden*,  u.a. *auf*, *bei*, oder *in* möglich.

Comment: Warum klingt dann *»in der Wikipedia«* in derselben Region offenbar korrekt?

Comment: Es klingt evtl für manche (nicht für mich korrekt), weil Wikipedia ein Kofferwort ist und man deshalb an "in der Enzyklopädie" denkt? Ich behaupte aber, korrekt ist es nicht. Wir sprechen ja auch im Norden kein reines Standarddeutsch.

Comment: Ich bezweifle, dass mehr als 5% aller Menschen bekannt ist, dass *Wikipedia* ein Kofferwort ist. Daher schenke ich dieser These wenig Glauben.

Comment: Stimmt wohl. Dann würde ich vermuten, dass es daran liegt, dass der Ausdruck **in (Obj.) finden** an sich nicht mit Namen kompatibel ist. Vergleiche: nach/zu Aldi http://www.spiegel.de/lebenundlernen/schule/zwiebelfibel-ich-geh-nach-aldi-a-398751.html

Comment: Edit: Pardon, es gibt natuerlich sowohl **in der** als auch **in**, z.B. In der Stadt & In (Stadtname).

Comment: Man sagt aber auch *im Duden* oder *im Knigge nachlesen* durchaus mit Artikel.

Comment: Stimmt. Ich guck dann noch mal in Ruhe.

Comment: @tofro: Der Duden, der Knigge, der Wahrig, der Brockhaus, der Jander/Blasius, der Hollemann-Wiberg, der Beilstein usw. sind lauter Bücher, die nach ihren Erst-Herausgebern bzw. Autoren benannt sind. Das ist eine eigene Kategorie von Eigennamen. Diese Namen von Büchern werden immer mit Artikel verwendet. Wikipedia gehört aber nicht in diese Kategorie, daher hilft ein Vergleich mit solchen Büchern nicht wirklich weiter.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Und "die Ilias", "das Rotkäppchen" (zugegeben nix, worin ich häufig nachschlage), oder "der Faust", oder sogar "die Bibel"?

Comment: @tofro: Auch dieser Vergleich setzt voraus, dass Wikipedia ein Buch sei. Dann würde man etwas *»**in** (der) Wikipedia«* finden oder lesen. Es geht mir aber nicht um *»**in**«*, sondern um *»**auf** (der) Wikipedia«*.

Answer (score 0):

Etwas **auf einer Webseite** zu lesen leitet sich von "web page" ab, das ist eine [Lehnübersetzung](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Webseite). (to read sth. on (a) (web) page) 
Die Übersetzung darf man nicht von "web site" herleiten, dieses Wort beschreibt vielmehr einen kompletten Webauftritt, der i.d.R. aus mehreren Einzelseiten besteht. Ob es nun an der ähnlichen Aussprache wie web site liegt oder nicht, jedenfalls hat sich das Wort Seite als Ersatz für einen kompletten Auftritt bzw. die Sammlung vieler Seiten unter einer Domain "eingebürgert". In den Anfängen des WWW bestand dieses auch noch aus viel mehr Einzelseiten, die qualitativ hochwertig waren und nur eine Thematik behandelten.

Schwierig zu beantworten ist sicherlich die Frage "ob es generell üblich ist". Das bedürfte einer statistischen Untersuchung. Ich für meinen Teil empfinde das Lesen "auf einer Seite" als nicht falsch, unabhängig davon, ob es sich um eine spezifische Seite oder eben eine Sammlung wie Wikipedia oder der Spiegel (etwas auf Spiegel Online lesen) handelt.

Der Name der "Seite" ist nun Wikipedia, von daher ist auch legitim von "auf der Wikipedia" (feminin Akkusativ von die Seite) zu sprechen, auch wenn es m.E. seltener verwendet wird als "auf Wikipedia" (ohne Artikel).

Comment: Ich bin Web-Entwickler, und unterscheide streng zwischen Website (der gesamte Internetauftritt eines Unternehmens), Webseite (irgend eine Seite dieses Internetauftritts) und Homepage (die Begrüßungsseite dieses Internetauftritts), stelle aber fest, dass weder meine Kunden noch sonst jemand diese Begriffe trennt. Diese drei Begriffe werden von der Überwiegenden Mehrheit der Bevölkerung als Synonyme verwendet. Das macht es dann leider schwierig, sich verständlich zu machen, wenn man als Webentwickler und -Designer mit seinen Kunden genau darüber reden muss.