# Stammt von oder stammt aus bei einer Quellenangabe

Tags: standard-german

Meine Bachelorarbeit umfasst ein Beispiel zu einem Algorithmus. Ich möchte in einer Fußnote kenntlich machen, woher das Beispiel stammt. Es ist ein Beispiel aus einer Website.

Heißt es nun "Das Beispiel stammt von www.blablab.de" oder "Das Beispiel stammt aus www.blablab.de" ?

Comment: Siehe auch https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/40861/auf-im-wikipedia . Insbesondere des Fazits. Entsprechend würde ich dies hier ebenso als Interpretationssache ansehen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bei »aus« denke ich zuerst an ein Buch, bei »von« zuerst an einen Autor. Dennoch ist beides auch in Bezug auf Webseiten möglich. Es geht allerdings einfacher:

> ¹Quelle [des Beispiels]: www.blabla.de

Es ist also gar nicht notwendig, dem Leser den Konsum einer Präposition abzuverlangen.

Answer (score -1):

*XYZ stammt* * *aus einer Webseite* ist schlicht und ergreifend kein Deutsch. Es ist nach wie vor **von**.

Comment: Willkommen! Ich würde Dir dringend ein wenig Lektüre ans Herz legen: Die [tour] für einen ersten Überblick, das [help] und [answer] um unser Format und die Erwartungen an alle Benutzer besser zu verstehen und der Stack Exchange [Code of Conduct](https://german.stackexchange.com/conduct) für die elementaren Verhaltensregeln der Community.